# How do I make a table of descriptive statistics for selected data in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of descriptive stats for a data set which prints like this:
[image]

However, I find this to be messy. I want it to look this way:
[image]
How do I do this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: have a look at [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `df.describe()` on your whole dataframe (or selected columns). The method selects all numeric columns by default:

```
>>> df.describe()
               A          B          C          D
count  10.000000  10.000000  10.000000  10.000000
mean   10.500000   9.800000   6.900000   5.800000
std     6.467869   6.746192   4.931757   4.802777
min     2.000000   1.000000   1.000000   0.000000
25%     5.000000   3.750000   4.000000   1.250000
50%    11.000000  10.000000   6.000000   6.500000
75%    15.000000  15.750000   9.000000   8.000000
max    19.000000  19.000000  18.000000  15.000000

>>> df
    A   B   C   D
0  15  12   4   0
1  15   1   6  10
2   5  19   1   1
3   5   3  18   1
4   7  17   4   6
5  15   9   6   8
6  18  11  11   7
7   4   2   6  15
8  19   6   3   2
9   2  18  10   8
```